# switching from standard deviation to moving average in a function

Tags: r, function

I am removing the erroneous data values from my data set. Till now I was doing it by following method:

Suppose z[,1] is my time series variable.ei s are the respective elements in it.
`std_d is sd(abs( diff(z[,1], lag=1) ))`

```
e1-e2> std_d... remove e2.
e1-e3> std_d...remove e3
e1-e4<std_d...move on to e4
e4-e5 <std_d..move on e5
e5-e6>std_d...remove e6
e5-e7<std_d...move on e7
```

I am doing this using the following code:

```
   zx <- as.numeric(coredata(z[,1]))
 coredata(z[,1]) <- Reduce(function(y,xx){ 
                          if( abs(tail(y[!is.na(y)], 1) - xx) > std_d ) {
                                    c(y,NA)} else { 
                                    c(y,xx)} }, 
                              zx )
```

My question is:

I want to switch from std_d i.e. standard deviation of lag difference to 'moving standard deviation'. For example if we are checking e20 , std_d should be--> std deviation of difference of 15 elements before it and 15 elements after it, with lag=1.

I was thinking of using roll mean in zoo. But I failed to fit it in the above function.
How can it be done?

Thank you for your time and consideration.
Here is the sample data:

```
           "timestamp" "mesured_distance" "IFC_Code" "from_sensor_to_river_bottom"
   "1" "2012-06-04 21:30:09-05" 4818 995 5030
   "2" "2012-06-04 21:15:11-05" 4820 995 5030
   "3" "2012-06-04 21:00:10-05" 4818 995 5030
   "4" "2012-06-04 20:45:10-05" 4817 995 5030
   "5" "2012-06-04 20:30:09-05" 8816 995 5030
   "6" "2012-06-04 20:15:09-05" 4816 995 5030
   "7" "2012-06-04 20:00:08-05" 4811 995 5030
   "8" "2012-06-04 19:45:07-05" 15009 995 5030
   "9" "2012-06-04 19:30:07-05" 4810 995 5030
   "10" "2012-06-04 19:15:09-05" 4795 995 5030
```

Comment: You cannot test conditions on the prior 15 items for any items before row number 16 and it doesn't make any sense to check into the future if the goal is some sort of prediction. I have no idea what a lag=1 means in this case.

Comment: 1. I am okay with starting the checking from the 16th element.
2. lag=1:-
std_d=sd(abs(diff(x, lag=1)))
similarly, I want to use this:
std_d=sd (abs( diff(X, lag1)))...In this case X should have previous and next 15 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps... untested in absence of data:

```
zx <- as.numeric(coredata(z[,1]))
coredata(z[,1]) <- Reduce(function(y,xx){ 
                          if( length(y) <15) {c(y,xx) } else {
                          if( abs(tail(y[!is.na(y)], 1) - xx) > std(tail( y, 15) ) {
                                    c(y,NA)} else { 
                                    c(y,xx)}                                       } 
                                          }, 
                              zx )
```

Can't be sure I got the parens and braces matched properly without testing

Comment: Sorry, it is not working. I've edited the question and given some sample data (first 10 rows of 10,000 rows). If you can give me your email id I can send you a data file if you want.